# How to end a loop with 0?

Tags: c, loops

I'm new to C and have a basic program which asks the user for a number and then prints this number along with the range it is in so 1-49 for instance.

Comment: It would be much more clear if you posted your code. Also, what range? If I enter `7` then what exactly is your program supposed to do?

Comment: If you posted 7 it would print 7 and print another statement to display that it is in the 1-49 range. (Goes up to 100, if the user inputs a larger number they get a statement and the program asks for a different number.)

Comment: Put your code for getting their number and responding with a message inside an infinite loop. When they enter a `0` break the loop or exit the program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  In general, you will get a better response if you show the code you've tried as your best attempt, rather than simply asking a question without showing anything.  This can help in several ways.  First, it shows that you've put some effort into solving your problem.  Second, it encourages you to ask about what's wrong with your attempt.  And third, it shows those who might help roughly what level you're programming at.  It means they are less likely to provide an answer that is too complicated for you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");

        char buf[10];
        fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
        printf("You entered %s\n", buf);

        // Code for displaying the range

        if (buf[0] == '0')
            break;
    }

    printf("Outside the loop\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hate to be pedantic, but this will fail if you input a 0-padded number like 00384.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;

    do {
        // Read the number into n
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
            perror("scanf");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Check arbitrary condition
        if (n >= 1 && n <= 49) {
            printf("%d is in the range 1-49\n", n);
        }
    } while (n != 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Good code checks the return value of `scanf("%d", &n);` before using `n`.  Example: `if scanf("%d", &n) != 1) Print_Error_and_Exit()`

Comment: Nice code 1+, still for completeness change `return 0;` to be `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`